# How to autoincrement non-primary key column in hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, strategy-pattern

In Hibernate how do I set a non primary key column to start at a default value of 10000 and then increment it with insertion of each record?

For example first entry should be 10000 then 10001,10002 so on.

Note: This is not a primary key, so I am not sure what generation strategy to use here.

Answer (score 0):

The **Version** attribute may work.

Reference: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/